# How do I do a count function from within a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to create a trigger which will update the values in a column in another table but every attempt I try doesn't work. My setup is like this, The table `customer` updates the `customer audit` table everytime the customer addresses get updated in the `customer` table, from  the audit table I want to update the `addresschangedcount` column in the `customer` table for everytime the address is changed in the audit table while grouping by customer ID, so far my code is like this but it doesn't update the `customer` table:

```
create trigger Attempt3Advanced
on CustomerAudit
after update
as
if (update (AddressChangedCount))
begin
    UPDATE tblCustomer
    SET    tblCustomer.AddressChangedCount = inserted.AddressChangedCount
    FROM   tblCustomer
    JOIN inserted
        ON tblCustomer.AddressChangedCount = inserted.AddressChangedCount
end
```

Can anyone tell me where im going wrong and if possible provide some solutions?

Comment: Your code is only going to fire when the AddressChangedCount column is in the list of columns being updated in the Audit table. And since this is an audit table it probably shouldn't ever fire because you typically don't update an audit table, you only insert into them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You should not update a real table from an audit table.

And you should not store data redundantly. You can simply look up the audit table to determine the number of changes made to the address. And then your code sugests that there is a field `AddressChangedCount` in your audit table. Why is that? Isn't the number of address changes the number of address change records in the audit table already?

At last you want to update the customer's address change count, but you don't look up the record of the customer, but the records with the same count instead:

```
ON tblCustomer.AddressChangedCount = inserted.AddressChangedCount
```

My advice: Remove the count fields altogether. If you want a count, then count. Like this:

```
select c.customer_id, coalesce(ca.cnt, 0)
from tblcustomer c
left join
(
  select customer_id, count(*) as cnt
  from customeraudit
  where coalesce(old_address, '') <> coalesce(new_address, '')
) ca on ca.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```